# How to get the id value from a Rails model enum?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to understand how to use enums to help manage the different user status levels.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum user_status: [:active, :pending, :trial]
end
```

So now active is 0, pending is 1, and trial is 2.

So if I do this:

```
user.active?
```

This works fine, but currently when I am setting the value I am still doing this:

```
user.user_status = 0
```

I was hoping I could do something like:

```
user.user_status = User.UserStatus.trial
```

The point is I don't want to have to remember what index each enum value is.

Also, **if I change the order or add more user_status values, the index will change and I want to prevent bugs from me hardcoding the values in my codebase.**

Is there a better way to handle the enum index values?

Answer (score 3):

You can easily find the answer [simply reading the documentation](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html):

```
user.trial!
```

will set the status and update the record. For more variants you can refer to the docs.

Answer (score 0):

it works in next way:

```
user.trial!
```

[more detail](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html)